# Run a Python script without having Python installed

Tags: python, html, sftp

I have a customer who wants to retrieve some files using sftp. I managed to do it with Python on my machine.

Now, I want to implement the solution on his PC without having to install Python on his laptop. What would be the optimal solution?

Would py2exe be the solution?

Comment: If you want  to run on windows, creating an executable will work, otherwise for Linux and OS X, python comes preinstalled.

Comment: If the need is to download files with sftp, why not use a dedicated sftp client program?

Comment: It would be interesting to see your Python code. Also, if you convert your code into an executable then it's no longer a script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can use [Pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) to create an executable.

```
pip install -U pyinstaller
pyinstaller your_program.py
```

See [manual](https://pyinstaller.org/) for more information.